# Controller Route in Laravel giving null value

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

I'm using ZipArchive to download multiple pdf file as a zip file.

Getting following Error:

> ErrorException: ZipArchive::open(): Empty string as source

While debugging I'm getting following values:

```
$filenames: null
$job_id: null
$zipname: null
$zip: ZipArchive
```

page.php

```
<td style="text-transform: uppercase;">@if(@$value->analyse_bankname!=null) {{@$value->analyse_bankname}} @else {{@$value->bankname}} @endif  <a href="/analytics/download-report-zip?filenames={{@$value->filenameList}}&job_id={{@$value->job_id}}"><i class="fa fa-file-archive-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
```

`web.php` file:

```
 Route::get('/download-report-zip','analyticsAuth\statementController@downloadZip')->name('bank statement download');
```

Thank you for time and consideration.

**EDIT 1:**
I've installed ZipArchive and added extension in php.ini

> ZipArchive::open(): Empty string as source

Comment: If you're under a namespace, then `ZipArchive::CREATE` also needs the leading `\\`

Comment: I would also advice against using `@` in the way you are. Validate variables and handle issues properly instead of just suppress errors like that. Specially when you later just assume the variables are properly set and while debugging your code (which tend to get way harder if you hide potential errors)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, After removing `@` also. I'm getting null value.

Comment: The new issue seem to be that you don't have the data you think you do in your request. How is that data sent to the script? Have you debugged it to see what you actually get?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm passing data from `web.php`.

Comment: You seem to only be passing `?zipname={{@$value->zipname}}`, so where would `$request->filenameList` and `$request->job_id` come from?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, How do i pass multiple value in `?zipname=`.

Comment: `http://example.com?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3` and so on. Separate them with `&`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, I tried `<td style="text-transform: uppercase;">@if(@$value->analyse_bankname!=null) {{@$value->analyse_bankname}} @else {{@$value->bankname}} @endif  <a href="/analytics/download-report-zip?filenames={{@$value->filenameList}}&job_id={{@$value->job_id}}"><i class="fa fa-file-archive-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>` But this also giving me same error.